# Float to percentage

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to convert the likes of `0.004` to `0.4%` (call it `bill_rate`).
Is there a built in function for percentage, or any easy way to do that?

Comment: What's your objective?  If it's displaying values with percents then formatting per Gordon's answer below makes sense.  If you're looking to use it as a percentage value (e.g. `25% * 200 = 50`) then Gordon's other point of multiplying your current figure by 100 makes more sense.  More info here (SQL Server answer, but the same concept applies to RedShift).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is `* 100`.  I think you want:

```
select to_char(bill_rate * 100, '0.0') || '%'
```

Comment: Ah perfect thank you. I was trying to keep it numeric and kept failing, but obviously this isnt numeric